# Ruby on Rails sneakily changing nested hash keys from symbols to strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, hash

I'm encountering something strange in Ruby on Rails. I am working on a website that allows users to purchase certain things and go through a multi-step checkout process. I use a session object as a hash to carry data over to other actions in the controller.

Here's what it basically looks like

```
class CheckoutController < ApplicationController
  def index
    #stuff
  end
  def create
    #stuff

    session[:checkout_data] = {} #initialize all the checkout data as hash
    # Insert the :items_to_purchase key with the value as a new Items model instance
    session[:checkout_data][:items_to_purchase] = Items.new(post_data_params) #as an example

    redirect_to :action => 'billing_info'
  end
```

So I've created some data in the first POST request of the form using the `Items` model. Let's go to the next page where the user enters billing info.

```
  def billing_info
    if request.get?
      @items_to_purchase = session[:checkout_data][:items_to_purchase]
    end
    if request.post?
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

My problem is on the line

```
@items_to_purchase = session[:checkout_data][:items_to_purchase].
```

The key `:items_to_purchase` doesn't exist, and instead, `'items_to_purchase'` is the key. What happened? I specifically initialized that key to be a symbol instead of string! Ruby changed it behind my back! It doesn't seem to do this if I only have one flat hash, but with these nested hashes, this problem occurs.

Anybody have any insight to what is happening?

Answer (score 6):

Sessions, if you're using cookie ones, do not live in Ruby - they are transmitted back and forth across the network. The `session` object you stored your data in is not the same `session` object that you tried to read it from. And while in cookie form, there is no difference between strings and symbols. Use `Hash#symbolize_keys!` to be sure you have your keys as you wish, or just use the string keys consistently.

Answer (score 0):

```
session[:checkout_data] = {} #initialize all the checkout data as hash
```

You are assigning here a normal Hash instead of ActionDispatch::Request::Session (that object is returned by session method).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem today.  Here is how I was able to solve it... hope this helps!

```
 def first_method
   session[:thing_to_store] = ThingToStore.new(params)).to_yaml
  end

 def second_method
   session[:thing_to_store] = YAML.load(session[:thing_to_store])
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to depend on your rails version, when I'm using 4.1.0, I have the same problem, but our older system with 4.0.3, using symbol as key to retrieve session works.